# Could the Dobhar Chú exist?

Tags: science-based, creature-design, evolution, mythical-creatures, cryptids

Residing in Ireland, the [Dobhar Chú](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobhar-ch%C3%BA) is a creature of Irish folklore being depicted as:

- being carnivorous
- resembling an Otter
- being 7 ft long
- residing in lakes (optional)
- hunting in pairs (optional)
- being mostly aquatic but capable of walking on land

Given these characteristics, what species could the Dobhar Chú have evolved from, and what evolutionary pressures would lead to such a creature?

NOTE: magic does not exist in my story

Comment: What reasons do you have to suspect such a creature couldn't exist? You've just described a really big otter.

Comment: Just for curiosity, what exactly is the astonishing caracter in the description of this animal?

Comment: [*Pteronura brasiliensis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_otter) is a real-life 6 ft (1.7 m) long otter, *plus* it has a 2 ft (0.7 m) long tail. Very large males reach a length of 8 ft (2.4 m).

Comment: There are also a bunch of extinct giant island otters. *Megalenhydris* from Sardinia was much bigger than any living otter (including *Pteroneura*), and a few other island otters seem to be pretty big. There are also some big mainland otters like *Enhydriodon* and *Siamogale*. Otters are one of the few groups of carnivores that easily disperse over water and Ireland has a lot of open niches for large predators only filled by wolves and brown bears. Honestly it's more surprising that something like the dobhar-chu didn't evolve in real life.

Comment: VTC: poor quality, as it's a copy-paste of other questions. Make this about your world or make it of use & interest to others! Always ask yourself: *what is the worldbuilding problem I need to solve?* before posting a query!

Answer (score 8):

**Otters already get this big**

The [Giant River Otter](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_otter) of the Amazon reaches up to seven feet in length and is a powerful predator. It’s highly social and lives throughout the Amazon basin. There is nothing astonishing or far fetched about a different species of otter getting this big in a cold climate like ireland, it just needs the right pressure.

Perhaps your Dobar Chú got big because they started to grab small land animals when the fish runs were low and have therefore gotten bigger and bigger to catch animals like small deer and unsuspecting humans.

Answer (score 5):

[Competition favors large bodies](https://www.nature.com/articles/482008d), so the easiest solution to your problem is just to make otters bigger, provided the ecosystem can support them. The "evolutionary pressure" making otters large would be the *lack* of pressure. The abundance of food and lack of competition would allow them to keep getting bigger. While this is the most obvious solution, I don't think a lake ecosystem would be a great place to evolve large mammals; food is relatively finite. I'd like to prose that -

**Dobhar Chú are extant [cetaceans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cetacea).**

Larger mammals than otters have evolved to live in marine environments. I propose that the Dobhar Chú are an offshoot of the lineage that produced whales and dolphins that didn't fully evolve to live in water. Perhaps they inherited cetaceans' size, but not their fins.

If you really want lake otters, check out the [seals of Lake Baikal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baikal_seal). Marine mammals have gotten trapped in freshwater ecosystems before; it wouldn't be infeasible for it to happen again.